# What is the best and most semantic way to concatenate large amounts of string/text in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Hi, sometimes we have to add paragraphs or large amounts of text to a javascript variable.
 Usually we want to break the var in various lines for better code reading and end up concatenating using:

```
        var x = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'+
        'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'+ 
        'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc' +
        'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'+
        'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc' +
        'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'+ 
        'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc' +
        'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'+
        'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc' +
```

Is there any better method, minding code reading, to concatenate large amounts of text in javascript? Another problem is that when we use 'auto format', the text editor/ide usually put the strings all together in the same line.

Comment: Perhaps store them in hidden HTML and read them in script?

Comment: Put a bunch of strings into an array, and call `.join("")` on it. Something like `var array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];` and then `array.join("")`

Comment: you can just do `x+="..";` on separate lines

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript has your answer.